# LAST_NUMBER on oracle sequence

Tags: oracle

I have a sequence SEQ_PAGE_ID

```
SEQUENCE_NAME   INCREMENT_BY  CACHE_SIZE   LAST_NUMBER            
-------------------------------------------------------
SEQ_PAGE_ID      1              20          2222292456
```

To change the CACHE_SIZE, I used below script,

`alter sequence SEQ_PAGE_ID CACHE 5000;`

When I checked the query,

```
select ... from user_sequences where sequence_name  = 'SEQ_PAGE_ID';


SEQUENCE_NAME   INCREMENT_BY  CACHE_SIZE    LAST_NUMBER            
-------------------------------------------------------
SEQ_PAGE_ID      1              5000          2222292447
```

The `LAST_NUMBER` changed from `2222292456` to `2222292447`. 
Is this happened due to the alter script?

Comment: In case, anybody landed here looking for what LAST_NUMBER is, here you go https://international-dba.blogspot.com/2012/07/lastnumber-column-in-dbasequences.html

Answer (score 22, accepted):

This is normal, yes. From the [documentation for the `all_sequences` data dictionary view](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18283_01/server.112/e17110/statviews_2062.htm), `last_number` is:

> Last sequence number written to disk. If a sequence uses caching, the number written to disk is the last number placed in the sequence cache. This number is likely to be greater than the last sequence number that was used.

This can be recreated with a fresh sequence:

```
SQL> create sequence SEQ_PAGE_ID start with 2222292436 increment by 1 cache 20;

sequence SEQ_PAGE_ID created.

SQL> select sequence_name, increment_by, cache_size, last_number
  2  from user_sequences where sequence_name = 'SEQ_PAGE_ID';

SEQUENCE_NAME                  INCREMENT_BY CACHE_SIZE LAST_NUMBER
------------------------------ ------------ ---------- -----------
SEQ_PAGE_ID                               1         20  2222292436 

SQL> select SEQ_PAGE_ID.nextval from dual;

   NEXTVAL
----------
2222292436 

SQL> select sequence_name, increment_by, cache_size, last_number
  2  from user_sequences where sequence_name = 'SEQ_PAGE_ID';

SEQUENCE_NAME                  INCREMENT_BY CACHE_SIZE LAST_NUMBER
------------------------------ ------------ ---------- -----------
SEQ_PAGE_ID                               1         20  2222292456
```

The `last_number` jumped up by the cache size, which is normal.

```
SQL> alter sequence SEQ_PAGE_ID CACHE 5000;

sequence SEQ_PAGE_ID altered.

SQL> select sequence_name, increment_by, cache_size, last_number
  2  from user_sequences where sequence_name = 'SEQ_PAGE_ID';

SEQUENCE_NAME                  INCREMENT_BY CACHE_SIZE LAST_NUMBER
------------------------------ ------------ ---------- -----------
SEQ_PAGE_ID                               1       5000  2222292437
```

The `last_number` goes down, but now reflects the actual last sequence number generated. The DDL has (apparently) caused the data written to disk to be updated to reflect what happens to be the current value, rather than the top of the cache - either the old 20-value cache or the new 5000-value cache. In your case you got `2222292447`, which just means you were ten values further through the cache than I was when I ran the `alter`.

The value saved to disk is largely there so that if the database crashes it knows where to pick up from. On restart the sequence will start generating numbers from the recorded `last_number`. During normal running it doesn't need to refer back to that, it just updates the value on disk when new values are cached. This prevents sequence numbers being reissued after a crash, without needing to do expensive (slow) locking to maintain the value in real time - which is what the cache is there to avoid, after all.

There would only be a problem if the `last_value` was lower than an actual generated sequence, but that can't happen. (Well, unless the sequence is set to cycle).

```
SQL> select SEQ_PAGE_ID.nextval from dual;

   NEXTVAL
----------
2222292437
```

The next sequence number generated follows on from the last one before the cache size change; it hasn't reused an old value as you might have been worried about from the dictionary value.

```
SQL> select sequence_name, increment_by, cache_size, last_number
  2  from user_sequences where sequence_name = 'SEQ_PAGE_ID';

SEQUENCE_NAME                  INCREMENT_BY CACHE_SIZE LAST_NUMBER
------------------------------ ------------ ---------- -----------
SEQ_PAGE_ID                               1       5000  2222297437
```

The `last_number` now shows the previous stored value incremented by the cache size of 5000. What is in the data dictionary now won't change again until we've consumed all 5000 values form the cache, or something happens elsewhere that affects it - the database being bounced, the sequence being altered again, etc.

Answer (score 7):

When the sequence is in cache, last_number represent the number keep by oracle.
When not, it represents the last sequence use by Oracle.
With your alter command, you change the settings of the sequence, so Oracle flush it's "sequence cache"

Here a simple example

```
SQL> drop sequence test;
Sequence dropped

SQL> create sequence test cache 20;
Sequence created

SQL> select last_number  from user_sequences where sequence_name='TEST';
LAST_NUMBER
-----------
          1

SQL> select test.nextval from dual;
   NEXTVAL
----------
         1

SQL>  select last_number  from user_sequences where sequence_name='TEST';
LAST_NUMBER
-----------
         21

SQL> alter sequence test CACHE 5000;
Sequence altered

SQL>  select last_number  from user_sequences where sequence_name='TEST';
LAST_NUMBER
-----------
          2

SQL> select test.nextval from dual;
   NEXTVAL
----------
         2

SQL>  select last_number  from user_sequences where sequence_name='TEST';
LAST_NUMBER
-----------
       5002

SQL>
```

Answer (score 0):

This post is for changing Last Number :)

Let us assume LAST_NUMBER in seq xyz is **3953** and you want to change it to **205233**, then you need to increment the sequence by (**205233 - 3953 = 201,280**) and then increment it by 1. that can be achieved by below statements:

to change the LAST_NUMBER to

```
ALTER SEQUENCE xyz INCREMENT BY 201280;
SELECT xyz.nextval from dual;
ALTER SEQUENCE xyz INCREMENT BY 1;
```

Now the LAST_NUMBER would be updated as **205233**