# Difference between Oracle sequence last number and max id inserted

Tags: oracle, triggers, sequences

I'm working on a application used by multiple users. They can insert, delete and update rows in the database which fires triggers what write into log tables. The problem is that the difference between the maximum id inserted in the log table and the last number generated by the sequences used by the trigger is changing continously. Sometimes an primary key exception is generated because the the sequence generate values that are already inserted in the table.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE 
TRIGGER EVALUACION.TCALIF_DEL
AFTER DELETE ON EVALUACION.CALIFICACIONES FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
INSERT INTO LOG_CALIFICACIONES (ID_BITACORA, ID_EVALUACION, ANIO, CALIFICACION, OBSERVACION, USUARIO, FECHA_HORA, TIPO_OPERACION_BD)
SELECT SEQ_CALIF.NEXTVAL, :OLD.ID_EVALUACION, :OLD.ANIO, :OLD.CALIFICACION, :OLD.OBSERVACION, :OLD.USUARIO, :OLD.FECHA_HORA, 'D' FROM DUAL;
END;

CREATE OR REPLACE 
TRIGGER EVALUACION.TCALIF_INS
AFTER INSERT ON EVALUACION.CALIFICACIONES FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
INSERT INTO LOG_CALIFICACIONES (ID_BITACORA, ID_EVALUACION, ANIO, CALIFICACION, OBSERVACION, USUARIO, FECHA_HORA, TIPO_OPERACION_BD)
SELECT SEQ_CALIF.NEXTVAL, :OLD.ID_EVALUACION, :OLD.ANIO, :OLD.CALIFICACION,:OLD.OBSERVACION, :OLD.USUARIO, :OLD.FECHA_HORA, 'I' FROM DUAL;
END;

CREATE OR REPLACE 
TRIGGER EVALUACION2010.TCALIF_UPD
AFTER UPDATE ON EVALUACION.CALIFICACIONES FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
INSERT INTO LOG_CALIFICACIONES (ID_BITACORA, ID_EVALUACION, ANIO,  CALIFICACION, OBSERVACION, USUARIO, FECHA_HORA, TIPO_OPERACION_BD)
SELECT SEQ_CALIF.NEXTVAL, :OLD.ID_EVALUACION, :OLD.ANIO, :OLD.CALIFICACION,   :OLD.OBSERVACION, :OLD.USUARIO, :OLD.FECHA_HORA, 'U' FROM DUAL;    END;
```

The code for the sequence is:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE "EVALUACION"."SEQ_CALIF"  
MINVALUE 1 
MAXVALUE 999999999999999999999999999 
INCREMENT BY 1 
START WITH 11114992 
CACHE 20 
NOORDER  
NOCYCLE  
NOPARTITION;
```

Comment: show us the trigger code and the code creating the sequence please

Comment: If you are using the sequence properly, you'd call `nextval` to get the next value and `currval` to get the last value that was generated in the current session.  If you use it properly, no two sessions will get the same value (barring cases where you have set the sequence to cycle and you exceed the maximum allowed value and start again from the lowest allowed value).  If that's not what you are seeing, you have a bug in your code.  We'd need to see the code you're using.

Comment: Why is your insert trigger using `:OLD` values, which will always be null? How are you seeing the 'last number generated by the sequence' - from querying user_sequences.last_number? That is [related to caching](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23632947/266304) and isn't supposed to be the last value actually used by a session. If you're getting a key clash then do you already have manually entered rows with higher values, or anything that is inserting without using the sequence?

Comment: I checked all the code and the insertions, deletions, updates are executed only by these triggers.

Comment: What about existing data? The `START WITH 11114992` suggests it already had data before you started using the sequence, so are there rows which have old manually-created IDs that are higher than the sequence value? What is the current maximum ID and sequence.nextval?

Comment: What is the PK of the log table?

Comment: The PK of the log table is id_bitacora

Comment: `...that the difference between the maximum id inserted in the log table ..` - is that mean, that there is another process/procedure that inserts records into this table using `SELECT max(id) + 1` method instead of getting next id from the sequence ?

Comment: Well, what you've shown and stated can't generate a clash on that key. So somebody is doing other inserts you aren't aware of, or you're misinterpreting the error you get. Are you sure that is the constraint referenced in the error - it isn't actually complaining about a primary/unique key on `CALIFICACIONES`, for example? It would help if you included the table structures and all constraints, a sample insert and the error message/stack it gets.