# Finding max value of multiple columns from multiple tables to update Sequence

Tags: sql, oracle11g, sequence

I had a problem where the DBAs needed to recreate my sequence (had to create with "NO CACHE".  Unfortunately, he dropped the sequence before grabbing the current value! The problem is, from what I can tell, there are almost 25 tables that use this sequence.  My plan was to try to find the max value of each of the Primary Key "ID" fields, then run a sequence loop to get the sequence back up.

What I'm hoping to do now, is clean up my "ugly" process for a more streamlined process that I can put in my documentation (in the event this occurs again!).

My original solution was do something like the following:

```
SELECT 'TABLE_1','TABLE_1_ID', MAX(TABLE_1_ID) from TABLE_1
UNION ALL
SELECT 'TABLE_2','TABLE_2_ID', MAX(TABLE_2_ID) from TABLE_2
UNION ALL 
SELECT 'TABLE_3','TABLE_3_ID', MAX(TABLE_3_ID) from TABLE_3
UNION ALL 
...... (continue select statements for other 20+ tables)
SELECT 'TABLE_25','TABLE_25_ID', MAX(TABLE_25_ID) from TABLE_25
ORDER BY 2 DESC;
```

This shows works, but putting the table with the highest "MAX" at the top; but to clean it up I'd like to:
1.  Simplify the query (an eliminate the UNION ALL) if possible
2.  I'd really like to just run the query that returns a single row..

3. This would be 'gravy', but I have a loop that will run through the next val of the sequence; that loop starts off with:

   ```
   declare
   COL_MaxVal pls_integer;
   SEQ_Currval pls_integer default -1;

   BEGIN
      SELECT MAX(TABLE_X_ID) INTO COL_MaxVal
      FROM TABLE_X
      while SEQ_Currval < COL_MaxVal
        loop
        select My_Sequence_SEQ.nexval into SEQ_Currval
        from dual;
      end loop;
   end
   ```

   If possible, I'd really like to just run the loop script which would discover which table/column has the highest max value, then use that table in the loop to increment the sequence to that max value.

Appreciate any help on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is solution returning one row:

```
    WITH all_data as
    (
        SELECT 'TABLE_1','TABLE_1_ID', MAX(TABLE_1_ID) as id from TABLE_1
        UNION ALL
        SELECT 'TABLE_2','TABLE_2_ID', MAX(TABLE_2_ID) from TABLE_2
        UNION ALL 
        SELECT 'TABLE_3','TABLE_3_ID', MAX(TABLE_3_ID) from TABLE_3
        UNION ALL 
        ...... (continue select statements for other 20+ tables)
        SELECT 'TABLE_25','TABLE_25_ID', MAX(TABLE_25_ID) from TABLE_25
    ),
    max_id as
    (
        SELECT max(id) as id FROM all_data
    )
    SELECT 
        ad.* 
    FROM 
        all_data ad 
    JOIN max_id mi ON (ad.id = mi.id)
```

I can not see any simpler solution for this...

Comment: Sorry it has taken so long to get back to this!  I've tried this and it works perfectly!  I believe I understand how this works, but just one question.  On the first "SELECT 'TABLE_1"  I see the "as id", why do I not need the "as id" on each line?  Thanks !

Comment: I do not think there is some SQL standard rule for this, but result of UNION statement tends to return column names from first statement. So, even if You would use `as id1` and `as id2` on other lines, the result would use `id`.

Comment: Thanks, I believe you are correct; I've been playing around with UNION ALL , where I was grabbing some count(*) from several different tables; I'm seeing the same behavior regardless of any other aliases I create. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

If it's not too late then dba might try flashback query against dictionary. E.g.

```
SELECT * FROM dba_sequences AS OF TIMESTAMP systimestamp - 1/24;
```

Your safe value should be last_number+cache size. See details in:

[LAST_NUMBER on oracle sequence](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23631628/last-number-on-oracle-sequence)

Comment: Thanks, too late for DBA to help on this; I've manually incremented (with a sql loop).   THanks for the response!  KSl.