# PL/SQL Package - package level variable failing to increment

Tags: oracle, plsql

I am having a PL/SQL package calling from Java.  Declared a variable at package level and using inside procedure in the pacakge. Incrementing the variable value on each call of the procedure but some of the scenario's it is getting failed.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY TestIncrement AS
    v_counter number(19):=0;
PROCEDURE saveItem(evalId IN NUMBER,id IN NUMBER, name IN varchar2) IS
BEGIN
  IF v_counter=0 THEN
    select MAX_SEQ+1 into v_counter from temptable where eval_id=evalId;  
  ELSE
     v_counter :=v_counter +1;
  END IF;
  Insert into item(id, counter, counter_name) values(id , v_counter , name)
END;
END TestIncrement;
```

Most of the time it is working fine but increment(v_counter :=v_counter +1) is getting failed one or two times. It is returning same number instead of increment. Both temptable and item are Global Temporary tables.

Comment: `values(id , counter, name)` should be `values (id, v_counter, name)`

Comment: Also, you cannot specify the string length in the procedure's signature; it should just be `name IN varchar2`. Fix those and a missing `;` and your package appears to work [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/BvmfW0l6).

Comment: Does `temptable` is a regular table?  Extend your question by adding `temptable` and `item` table definitions and constraints.

Comment: Thanks for quick reply. Sorry I corrected both mistakes while typing. Actual issue is increment is not happening properly 1 in 100 times.  Dont know why it is happening. some times same number is assigning to multiple records

Comment: @robertus Thanks for quick response. both tables are global temp tables.

Comment: @pramagouni put table definitions and explain how these tables are used by application - because all global temp tables are empty at session creation. And if `temptable` is not populated with data, your code has no sense. In general you're code has many mistakes - you're not taking into account working with multiple users (sessions). Maybe you should state what are you trying to accomplish in general (at business logic level) and then we will could point you in the right direction. There are sequences, session scoped sequences, transactional `select for update` etc.

Answer (score -1):

The main problem is that the procedure calls are not in the same database session. If you wish to have something incremented no matter what calls that procedure, then use a sequence, and, to get the last value for that sequence, use a select like:

```
select last_number
from all_serquences seq
where seq.sequence_owner=p_owner and seq.sequence_name=p_sequence_name;
```

Or, if you wish a value to be incremented when called from an instance of that application, then you should have that value managed by the application, not in the database

Comment: That's a wrong answer for multiprocessing environments. It will be correctly only for database transaction in `serializable mode` or - at application level - for applications with only one instance with one process at a time (like only 1 worker). In general, for getting next number from sequence is `SEQ_NAME.nextval` method but it will not be valid for all cases (for ex. if you must have continuous sequence of numbers without any gaps).

Comment: You're probably right about the sessions, but your query is not correct if the sequence has a cache. [From the docs](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/refrn/ALL_SEQUENCES.html), `last_number` is: "Last sequence number written to disk. If a sequence uses caching, the number written to disk is the last number placed in the sequence cache. This number is likely to be greater than the last sequence number that was used." and "For session sequences, the value in this column should be ignored."  ([Slightly related Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23632947/266304)).

Comment: @AlexPoole thanks for explicit pointing out `cache` size influence on `last_number` - I've forgot about that aspect. There is an option to turn that cache off (`NOCACHE`), but still - solution presented in this answer shouldn't be considered valid.